# UIControl Subclass Not triggering touch events. [iOS]

Tags: ios, swift, uicontrol

I have create a subclass of UIControl, where all the events is working fine when there is no gesture recogniser added to its parent view. But when I add tap gesture to its parent view no events are triggering.

```
class CustomControl: UIControl {


}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var customControl: CustomControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        customControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didTapOnView(_:))))
}
```

I have tried by alter isUserInteraction property for itself and its subviews but no success. I am not getting any response in `didTap(_ sender: Any)` method, After adding gesture.

Comment: If you want `didTap` to be called, why did you add a gesture recogniser then? Why do you have two different methods (`didTap` and `didTapOnView`) to handle taps?

Comment: Actually the requirement is - I Need to check any tap whole view, as well as any touch event occur in the custom control. So `didTapOnView` to check tap on parent view. And `didTap` to check tap on customControl view.